# Error on code using createAsyncThunk in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to create a react app using Typescript and after a bunch of errors starting to regret about this decision lol. It's much more verbose than using JS/Babel.

But let's go for the real problem. I've created this custom hook:

useGetDeviceById.ts

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'src/hooks';
import { fetchStatus } from 'src/shared/constants';
import { getDeviceById } from 'src/features/device/redux/deviceOperations';
import { getDevice, getDeviceFetchError } from 'src/features/device/redux/deviceSelectors';

const useGetDeviceById = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { deviceId } = useParams<{deviceId?: string}>();

  const device = useAppSelector(getDevice);
  const hasGetError = useAppSelector(getDeviceFetchError);
  const isDeviceLoading = device.fetchStatus.getProposalById !== fetchStatus.fulfilled;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasGetError) push('/');
    else {
      dispatch(getDeviceById(deviceId));
    }
  }, [push, hasGetError, dispatch, deviceId]);

  return { device: { ...device, deviceId }, isDeviceLoading}
};

export default useGetDeviceById;;
```

deviceOperations.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { loaderActions } from '../../../features/loader/redux';
import deviceManager from '../deviceManager';

export const getDeviceById = createAsyncThunk(
  'device/GET_DEVICE_BY_ID',
  async (deviceId: number, { dispatch }) => {
    dispatch(loaderActions.start('getDeviceById'));
    try {
      const device = await deviceManager.getDeviceById(deviceId);
      return { ...device, deviceId };
    } finally {
      dispatch(loaderActions.stop('getDeviceById'));
    }
  }
);
```

I'm getting the error below on `dispatch(getDeviceById(deviceId));`:

```
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, number, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, number, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.  TS2345

    18 |     if (hasGetError) push('/');
    19 |     else {
  > 20 |       dispatch(getDeviceById(deviceId));
       |                ^
    21 |     }
    22 |   }, [push, hasGetError, dispatch, deviceId]);
    23 |
```

Can you help me? Is it the correct way to create this stuff?